# How to add item in JList ?

Tags: java, oop, jlist

I am unable to add items into my JList for some unknown reasons. There are 2 classes that I am trying to working on. There are: Class A & Class B.

Inside Class A, I have one button called "Add". If I click this Add button, it should add items into JList that is on Class B. The variable for JList is called "jAddList".

So what I did in Class A:

```
Public class A extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    public B addItem;
    private final B JListFrame = new B();

    private void jButtonAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        JListFrame.setVisible(true);

        DefaultListModel modelAddList = new DefaultListModel();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
                modelAddList.addElement(i);
        }

        addItem.jAddList.add(modelCmdList);

       }
}
```

However, it does not works. The compiler software (Netbean) thrown me warnings:

**Output:**

```
no suitable method found for add(DefaultListModel)
   method Component.add(PopupMenu) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; DefaultModel cannot be converted to PopupMenu)
   method Container.add(Component) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; DefaultModel cannot be converted to Component)
```

***Thanks!***

Comment: Naming a variable like a class is really confusing, you should change that.

Comment: Sorry for confusing, Robin. I will be aware next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setModel` to set the model for the `JList` component

```
jAddList.setModel(listModel);
```

A single model can be set at startup to be manipulated later

```
JList<Integer> jAddList = new JList<>(listModel);
```

Comment: Thanks Reimeus. That did solve my problem. The code can runs but it still cant show me the output. Do you spot any error on my code? I did changed my code to " public B addItem; " to " public B addItem = new B() ; " The JList was just a empty list without any items. That shouldn't be...somewhere must went wrong.